Does randomness interrupt causal chains?
My question is inspired by the following thought-provoking comment by Philomath:

A measurement causes a quantum system to decohere, but it doesn't determine the outcome. With radioactive decay, for example, the cause lies in the formation of a nucleus that brings the nucleus in a superposition of decay and non-decay. The outcome is indeterminate but the cause is clear even if it lies millions of years in the past. If I place a bucket of uranium in your room and you get sick then according to your view I am not responsible because there is no causal chain. It is uncaused. So how could I be the cause?

This was in response to an earlier comment by Syed:

Indeterminate is the same as uncaused. Because if nothing determines a quantum event, then nothing sufficiently causes it if that makes sense. And as of now, we don’t know if this is truly random or whether there is something happening behind the scenes.

In other words, suppose we have the following sequence of events:
A -> B -> C -> D -> [something truly random under conditions facilitated by D] -> E -> F -> ... -> Z
Would the statement "A caused Z" be factually true? If not, does this mean that randomness interrupts causal chains?

BONUS: I cannot resist the temptation to entertain a very similar question in which one replaces "randomness" with "free will" and asks whether moral responsibility would be interrupted by "free will" (if A and Z were conscious agents), but I don't want the question to get closed as unfocused, so let's put that aside for now...

"truly random" and "triggered by D" do not seem compatible.

@controlgroup why?

Like Syed said: if it's truly random, then no other event is sufficient cause for it. If it was triggered by another event D, then you could say that D was sufficient cause given that it would not have happened without D occurring.

@controlgroup What about the word "facilitated" instead, as in the rebuttal by Philomath in which he places a bucket of uranium in Syed's room?

Logically speaking the event Syed's getting sick in that case is also attributable to Philomath, since getting sick isn't a truly random event. P triggered the event by placing a toxin next to S to cause S to get sick. Although the intervening radioactive decays were random they could not have made S sick without P's intervention.

@controlgroup So how does any quantum process cause anything to happen?

Because, of course, the effect could not have occurred if one of the processes' possible outcomes was not one that is sufficient cause for the effect. In such a case, that outcome's (random) appearance is a perfectly-valid cause for any given effect. The fact that any given outcome is not guaranteed has no bearing.

It depends on what you mean by cause here. Some have interpreted A being a cause of B to imply A being a necessary precondition of B. For example, radioactive decay may have certain preconditions needed for the decay to occur, even if those conditions don’t tell you when it will decay. Usually though, what we mean by cause is a sufficient cause: a cause that completely determines the event. If the preceding event in a causal chain is uncaused, then technically, the final effect is uncaused. The question of whether quantum mechanics is fundamentally random is still an open question.

Note, though, that a necessary precondition for S getting six of radiation poisoning (reasonably) is that P put the uranium in the room, even though it's technically possible, uniform radiation distribution be damned, for S to dodge all the dangerous particles somehow (i.e. if you're willing to break the causal chain with randomness, you should also be willing to say that radiation isn't actually a sufficient cause for sickness).

P.S. If I get sick of radiation poisoning any time soon, I now know who to blame!

@controlgroup My point is to argue for causal closure in physics. I think radioactive decay is indeterminate, but not uncaused. It is much clearer when we look at proton collisions in the Large Hadron Collider where the collision of protons results in a plethora of particles. Even those are the result of particles that rapidly decay in millionths of a second, we would say they were caused by the collision. Decays is just a lot slower, but not fundamentally different in nature. I'll be gladly proven wrong by any physicist in the room, because I'd like to know this.

For the record: I did not place a bucket of Uranium in Syed's room!

@Philomath I wholeheartedly agree with that stance - I am of the opinion that a random event can still be cause for an effect so that that realm of physics is causally-closed. With my last comment I was trying to illustrate that, if random events end up producing uncaused events, then a lot of other holes open up, all of which would conveniently be filled by letting things like radioactivity be logically caused.

On standard definitions, A is a cause of B (not necessarily a sufficient cause) when it increases the probability of B, i.e. p(B | A) > p(B), plus conditions to exclude confounders, accidental correlations, common causes, etc. The way "causal chain" is used here requires p(B | A) = 1 for each link instead, and anything less is "truly random". With these 'definitions', everything is always "truly random" because no event "causes" any other event on its own, surroundings always contribute, and the only "cause" is the state of the entire universe. And even that only assuming determinism.

Sir Russell didn't even believe causality as essentially only a man-made convenient concept for some man-made or teleological purposes is a fundamental metaphysical feature of nature while randomness is, though you would hear dictums like "to be is to cause" for some conventional uses. Similarly physicist Weinberg warned the age old mechanistic causal chain mechanism had been obsolete since late 19th century full of causal Ether, if not counting from the discovery of Newton's universal gravity law, and hinders new physics progress like SR and QM on a epistemology level for many physicists...

No.
As a simple example, imagine a game of Russian Roulette. Spinning the cylinder doesn't break the causal link between pulling the trigger and the death of the target if the spin happens to land with the bulleted chamber selected.
Or a game of chance in a casino, such as a slot machine. Pulling the handle is the cause of winning or losing the money you bet, depending on the result of the machine's random actions. Just because you don't know which result will occur doesn't mean you didn't cause it.
When assessing moral culpability, we may consider the probability distribution of the random steps. If you play Russian Roulette with 5 out of 6 chambers filled, it's very likely that pulling the trigger will cause a shot; most people would consider the trigger puller to be guilty of murder (or attempted murder if the victim gets lucky). On the other hand, if you only load one chamber, we might be more lenient; we might consider it to be only manslaughter, because pulling the trigger is reckless (note: I'm not a lawyer, don't take this as legal advice).
This is why we don't generally consider quantum effects when dealing with cause and effect in the real world. In the macroscopic world that we ordinarily deal with, the probabilities of subatomic effects are averaged out and lost in the noise. If you let go of a ball, you can be practically certain that it will fall; if it's a heavy bowling ball and you let go above someone's foot, this is clearly the cause of any pain or injury that occurs. Quantum mechanics allows for a possibility that it won't fall or the atoms of the ball and foot will miss each other, but the probability is so infinitessimal that we can safely ignore it.
In an aside you asked whether free will breaks the causal link. Again, no. Suppose you're a mob boss and you tell one of your underlings to kill a rival. They have free will and can choose whether or not to obey the order. But if they carry it out, you are considered the ultimate cause of the rival's death.
In all these examples, what matters for causality is setting the chain of causes and effects in motion.


Does randomness interrupt causal chains?

Not necessarily. Your enjoyment of music on a radio station is not always interrupted by the random noise that is always in the background.
The effect of randomness on the signal is expressed as a signal-to-noise ratio. If the signal to noise ratio is too low. The causal chain (listening to music) is broken due to white noise static.
In digital communications, random events are constantly introducing errors in the data packets that can corrupt information (break the causal
chain)
To counter this corruption, all data packets contain error checking bytes as part of the structure. The simplest of these is a Checksum.
Whatever the protocol, an error checking failure (caused by a random event) causes a sequence of events that results in the re-transmission of the data packet until error checking passes. This keeps the causal chain alive. This goes on constantly in all digital communications.
The level of corruption by random effects on a piece of information is proportional to precision required to understand a message.
For example sending a photo of myself as a bitmap may have some random bits due to noise but that doesn't necessarily mean I can't be recognized.
But I want the digital information transferred in the digital defibrillator used to restart my heart to be exact.

I will try to break down where I think the disagreement stems from.
A -> B quantum superposition -> C
In normal life, you know tables and chairs, B is very short and we confidently state that C is the effect caused by A even though it has an uncertainty that agrees with Heisenberg's uncertainty principle. In this case A and C could be the reactants and products of any chemical reaction.
However, radioactive decay, which is most often used as an example of an uncaused event, feels very differently.
A -> B quantum superposition ------ millions of years ------------> C
Now we just see C, the sudden decay of a Uranium isotope and it seems uncaused. Now, I am not a physicist by training, so I have to support this idea. This post on the Physics SE seems to support this claim that in the case of radioactive decay the nucleus of a radioactive isotope is in a superposition of |decayed> and |undecayed>.
I think a lot of the confusion comes from the fact that in everyday life, determinism and causation are very closely linked. So, my answer would be that even though randomness (or uncertainty in outcomes before measurement) occurs, these events are still subject to causal closure.
This is my argument in defense of physical closure in quantum mechanics.
Again, I am not a physicist and I'd be gladly proven wrong by any physicist.

As an aside, I should have taken Potassium-40 as an example because this isotope occurs naturally in bananas. Some of it decays in your body as you read this... How cool is that?

I think you should discuss stochastic half-life models for radioactive decay to address the concept of acausal decay of a single unstable particle versus causal prediction for decay of a large number of such unstable particles.

@SystemTheory No, I want to precisely argue that the decay of single unstable particle is not acausal. The decay is directly caused by and by nothing else but the production of the Uranium in a supernova some 6 billion years ago. This caused the superposition of the decayed - undecayed quantum states. When the decay takes place is just the uncertainty of the event. Neutrons outside a nucleus will decay in a matter of minutes, but inside the U nucleus it is billions of years. It is like if I cause an asteroid to change course and after billions of years it crashes into Earth. I still caused it.

I do not deny that we experience causation and causal chains, or that we can create, for example, nuclear chain reactions by understanding models for the geometry and properties of materials. In legal analysis there is the concept of an infinite chain of causes back to an ultimate cause. But we deliberately cut off the chain of reasoning and focus on the proximate (nearby) cause of events. The model of the universe evolving forward from a Big Bang, later producing heavy elements, is backward reasoning in which (psychological) time is a division or multiplication of day and night.

@SystemTheory I am terribly sorry, but I don't understand. I don't even understand what you're arguing for or against?

No.
Randomness is a factor in every causal event.
Randomness is the inaccuracy between a cause and its effect. In a probabilistic universe causes never determine their effects with absolute precision. Only the probability distribution of the effect is determined by the cause.
In individual quantum events the effect is more random than in macro scale events, where billions of quantum events average out resulting in a more precise quasi-deterministic macro scale effect.

No. Randomness is an attribute of causal observations.
Revisiting causality using stochastics: 1. Theory
Demetris Koutsoyiannis, Christian Onof, Antonis Christofides and Zbigniew W. Kundzewicz
Published: 25 May 2022 https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.2021.0835
https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.2021.0835

The general question of how to define and identify causes remains however and this is the locus of the contemporary debate around the concept of cause. Many philosophers and mathematicians have attempted to answer it by developing theories of causation. These are based on interventions (A causes B if by deliberately creating A, B follows), counterfactuals (A causes B if B would not have occurred had A been absent), necessary and sufficient conditions (A causes B if A is necessary and sufficient for B to occur), or probability (A causes B if the presence of A increases the probability of B; see §2b). Combinations of these approaches have also been proposed. However, no completely satisfactory characterization has been formulated. Naturally, this philosophical perplexity is also reflected in the mathematical representation of causality, which defines the scope of our study. In particular, this paper and its companion are a contribution to the probabilistic approach to causality.

Google [ causation in stochastic models ]
AI Overview:

In a stochastic model, "causation" refers to the idea that a change in one variable (the "cause") is associated with a statistically significant change in another variable (the "effect"), even when considering the inherent randomness or uncertainty within the system, usually expressed through probability distributions; essentially, it means that manipulating the "cause" would likely lead to a predictable change in the "effect" despite the presence of random fluctuations.

Stochastic system models describe input variables, system parameters, and output variables that all theoretically vary with a respective error estimate. The input variables, system parameters, and error estimates are recognized as causally related to the output variables and output error estimate. Monte Carlo analysis is often used in the effort to understand the worst-case error estimate.

Downvoted because of the use of Google AI overview. This is not to be trusted. I have seen it spew out utter garbage. On top of that it is untraceable. If I use the same search terms (and I just tested it), I get a different outcome. It's fine for getting an idea, inspiration, or insights, but answers should be based on published citable sources or own ideas,

@Philomath I appreciate the AI Overview concern. However, the description of stochastic models seems to be in accord with my recollection from master's level engineering studies. Engineers design systems where the inputs, parameters, and outputs are given by stochastic models. One example is the rate at which calls are dropped in a communication network based on bandwidth availability and rate of use. During the earthquake on the West Coast in 1994 and East Coast in 2011 the spike in call volume caused many busy signals in the respective phone networks. Systemic financial crisis is stochastic.

The downvote is entirely due to the AI thing because I think that is important. I cannot undo it now unless you change some of the text apparently. I think you have a good point when it comes to stochastic models. I should also say that this question has a history and I wanted to argue against the idea of uncaused quantum events which came up in an earlier discussion which triggered this question. Indeterminate quantum events, and random effects, I agree with, but they are not uncaused in my view.
